# How can I download Wifi drivers for Ubuntu without internet (from alternate computer)?

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers, wifi-driver

I installed Ubuntu dual-boot and everything installed smoothly. However, that "install additional drivers during installation" (or something like that) option was disabled, probably because I couldn't connect to Wifi. Windows connects normally to Wifi, immediately finding it, so I suppose it's issue with Linux drivers. How can I fix this? Is there some link I can use to download drivers for my card? Thank you.

Comment: What network card are you using?

Comment: @MJ9 In Device Manager, under Network Adapters, there are 2 adapters: "Broadcom 802.11ac Network Adapter" and "Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller". I'm not sure which one is used for what.